# Cant get a basic "If Has Tag" Statement to work - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, if-statement, tags

I'm simply placing a small snippet of code on a woocommerce product page of my Wordpress website, to display an image "IF" the product has a specific TAG in place.

The code itself seems like it would be simple enough, and ive googled the heck out of this and tried many variations, with no luck on any of them.

```
<?php if( has_tag( 'tagnamehere') ) : ?> <div>my content</div> <?php endif; ?>
```

Also tried this:

```
<?php if( has_tag( 'tagnamehere' ) ){ echo '<div>my content</div>'; } ?>
```

Thats didnt work either.

basically, i just want it to look at the TAG of the product, and if the TAG exists, simply show the image (div). Nothing seems to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please share any code you've tried so you can be better assisted, and any answers can be better suited towards the issue at hand. Thanks!

Comment: sorry, first time using this site. Code was now pasted in! :)

Answer (score 1):

WordPress actually uses what's called [Taxonomies](https://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies) and Terms.

Taxonomies are basically a grouping of Posts or Custom Post Types (like 'Category' or 'Post Tag', and Terms are basically the individual grouping names 'Featured Posts', etc.

WooCommerce basically registers a [Custom Post Type](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Custom_Post_Types) called `product`, and also a Taxonomy called `product_tag`. Note, this is different than the default [Tags on Posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Posts_Tags_Screen).

Effectively this means you'll need to check if the `term` '`tagnamehere`' exists in the `product_tag` taxonomy, the easiest way would be with the [`has_term()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/has_term) function. This is basically like the "Custom Post Type with Custom Category *(aka Taxonomy)*" version of `has_tag()`

```
if( has_term( 'tagnamehere', 'product_tag' ) ){
    echo '<div>my content</div>';
}
```

Also to address your original "two versions" of code - The curly brace or alternative-syntax `if` statements work identically, and are mostly up to style/preference.

Comment: EUREKA! THAT WORKED! Thank you so much for showing me what piece i was missing! :) :)

Comment: Wonderful, glad to help! If you wouldn't mind, would you mark the answer as accepted (the checkmark on the left-hand side) so it may help other users with similar issues as they arise? Thanks!